# extern "C" variables affected by compiler optimization level

Tags: c++, gcc

Consider this [link](https://godbolt.org/z/39YKbaabM) with the snippet

```
#include <cstdio>

namespace X {
    extern "C" int z;
}

namespace Y {
    extern "C" int z;
}

int X::z = 1;
int main()
{
    std::printf("%d -- %d\n", X::z, Y::z);
    X::z = 2;
    Y::z = 4;
    std::printf("%d -- %d\n", X::z, Y::z);
    X::z = 0;
    std::printf("%d -- %d\n", X::z, Y::z);
}
```

With `-O1` GCC outputs

```
1 -- 1
2 -- 4
0 -- 0
```

whereas the output of GCC with no optimization enabled matches with that of CLANG (across all optimization levels) i.e.

```
1 -- 1
4 -- 4
0 -- 0
```

Is this a compiler bug in GCC because with `extern "C"` I'd expect name mangling to be disabled and thus there being only the variable `z` in both the namespaces and thus the values should always be the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a GCC bug. A similar test case has already been reported [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88806). (Although that one could be a bit more subtle than your test case because it also depends on how exactly `using namespace` lookup works).

As you are expecting the standard says that variable declarations with C linkage and the same name declared in different namespace scopes refer to the same entity, see [[dcl.link]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.link#7.sentence-3).